# Bootstrap Tab won't switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have two tabs in my sidebar at the right: http://www.futurebusinesscouncil.com/join-3/

Below the search you can see "Popular" and "Recent". I want to swtich that to Popular. Normally it should work with this code:

`jQuery('#tabs a[href="#tab-popular"]').tab('show');`

But sadly, it isn't switching the tab. Just the color is changing like it is active. But it isn't... Where is my failure?

Kind regards

Comment: You need to have unique `id`, in your case both the tabs are having same id `tabs`.

Answer (score 0):

On page load just add class named 'active' in the first li.

```
$('#tabs').find('li').removeClass('active');
$('#tabs').find('li:first').addClass('active');
```

Comment: But doesn't change the tab card from recent to popular

Comment: You stll see the recent card if you do that

Comment: Did you remove active class from the second li?

Comment: $('#tabs').find('li').removeClass('active');
$('#tabs').find('li:first').addClass('active');

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines of code

```
jQuery('#tabs a[href="#tab-recent"]').parent().removeClass("active")
jQuery('#tabs a[href="#tab-popular"]').parent().addClass("active")
```

Comment: Doesn't work either... I will do it with CSS and display now. This is working for me!

Comment: You are applying this code not in proper way. This code is working in browser console.